# Stop and continue execution from debugger possible?

Tags: debugging, matlab

Is there any way to stop the execution of a matlab program from the debugger like ctrl+c does, but then being able to continue execution (like you can in say c#)?

If not, is there any better way to workaround this other than trying to pre-emptively set break points or dbstop statements in your matlab code?

I would like to be able to interrupt a long running simulation to look at the current state and then continue the simulation.

The two options I'm currently using/considering are

1. dbstop commands (or (conditional) breakpoints) in the code.
   Drawback is that sometimes I don't want to stop the simulation for a few hours, sometimes want to stop after only a few seconds (and I don't necessarily know that in advance) and this doesn't work well with this approach: If I set the break condition to break every 5 minutes, I can't leave matlab running for hours without interaction. If I set the condition to higher, I have to wait too long for the condition to hit.
2. include code to save the workspace every few seconds/minutes and import the workspace into a second matlab instance. Drawback is that this is a huge hassle and also doesn't necessarily allows me to resume the simulation with the state of the saved workspace then step through the code for a few iterations.

I'm hoping there is a better solution than either of the 2. Thanks for any advice!

**Edit**: I think what I'm going to do is write simple matlab function that checks an environment variable or a file on disk every iteration and calls dbstop if I set a flag in this file or env. This way I can control when (and if needed which of several) the breakpoint hits from outside matlab by editing the file. Messy, but should work.

Comment: perhaps you could try conditional breakpoints

Comment: Thanks Amro, but conditional breakpoints/dbstops is what I'm doing in option 1, I perhaps should edit the question to make that more clear. It's not an ideal solution for me at all unfortunately, that's why I was hoping for a better option

Comment: Oh I just read your edit, exactly what I was thinking of..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not necessarily the best way, but you could simulate a file-based signal/interrupt framework. It could be done by checking every once in a while inside the long simulation loop for the existence of a specific file. If it does, you enter interactive mode using the `keyboard` command.

Something along the lines:

```
CHECK_EVERY = 10;    %# like a polling rate

tic
i = 1;               %# loop counter
while true           %# long running loop
    if rem(i,CHECK_EVERY) == 0 && exist('debug.txt','file')
        fprintf('%f seconds since last time.\n', toc)
        keyboard
        tic
    end

    %# ... long calculations ...    

    i = i + 1;
end
```

You would run your simulation as usual. When you would like to step in the code, simply create a file `debug.txt` (manually that is), and the execution will halt and you get the prompt:

```
2.803095 seconds since last time.
K>>
```

You could then inspect your variables as usual... To continue, simply run `return` (dont forget to temporarily rename or remove the file). In order to exit, use `dbquit`

---

**EDIT:** Just occurred to me, instead of checking for files, an easier solution would be to use a dummy figure as the flag (as long as the figure is open, keep running).

```
hFig = figure; drawnow
while true
    if ~ishandle(hFig)
        keyboard
        hFig = figure; drawnow
    end

    %# ...
    pause(0.5)
end
```

Comment: I was actually just thinking about perhaps doing something along those lines :)
Probably as good as it will get. Thanks!

Comment: @BenSchwehn: idea = use a dummy figure instead of external files

Comment: I like the figure idea! Won't work when running on the command line , but on the command-line I rarely want to to debug anyway. Nice, thanks!

Comment: It's a bit ridiculous that this is the only practical way to achieve this in MATLAB, but thank you for a nice hack and perfectly working solution!

Answer (score 10):

With the [release of R2016a](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?refresh=true#bu5rsdy-1), you can just hit the Pause button in the code editor and it will halt right away. The keyboard shortcut is Ctrl+F5.

> To pause the execution of a program while it is running, in the Editor tab, click the Pause button. MATLAB pauses execution at the next executable line*.

When your code is running, the Start button will turn into a pause:

[image]

Another change with this release is the ability to add/remove breakpoints while running.  Previously you couldn't do this, apparently.

Comment: I'll remove this in a few hours, but I just wanted to ping you regarding an `accumarray` success story.  The OP had code that was running for 10 minutes, and when I suggested `accumarray`, the runtime shrunk down to 2 seconds :D. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067363/counting-average-on-huge-matrix-with-conditional/38067869 - I was actually in your neighbourhood a few times over the last month... interviews. I should have remembered to reach out to you. Oops :( Maybe next time.  Hope all is well!

Comment: Pay careful attention to the `pauses execution at the next executable line` remark in the docs, that means that if the current command you are executing takes 2 hours to finish, Matlab will stop after 2 hours. It's not like Visual Studio where you can stop at the next CPU instruction in your program.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a [conditional breakpoint](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/brqxeeu-175.html#brqxeeu-234) in the MATLAB Editor. You can also use [DBSTOP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dbstop.html) to do this. For example, this will set a conditional breakpoint in the file `myFcn` at line 20 which will stop execution when a loop variable `i` is a multiple of 500:

```
dbstop in myFcn.m at 20 if rem(i,500) == 0
```

Then you can [continue execution](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dbcont.html) after you inspect some of your variables.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what meant I'm doing in my option 1 in the question. But as I said, this has the drawback that I don't know after how many minutes I want to stop a priori. i.e. if the 500 in the condition corresponds to 5 minutes execution, I can't simply leave the simulation running for a few hours but have to interact with matlab every 5 minutes or the sim stops. Conversely if I change the 500 to say 5000 (50 min runtime), I have to wait 50 minutes until matlab stops for the first time...

Answer (score 2):

If saving the workspace to a file is a good proxy for what you want, how about making a simple GUI with a toggle button.  In your code, check the state of the button.  If the button is depressed, save the state, update a static text to reflect time stamp of last save, unpress the button.  Optionally, have a conditional breakpoint based on the state of that toggle button.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution using the [`waitinput` File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28881-waitinput). 
The advantage is that you can use it from whithin the current session or in cases where it is troublesome to set up a file. Also it won't leave a file behind on the computer.

The downside is there as well unfortunately, you need to wait for the checking moment before you can terminate and it costs a little bit of time.

```
for t = 1:10
    pause(3) %Doing some calculations
    str = waitinput('Enter 1 if you want to stop ',5);
    if ~isnan(str)
        keyboard; % Enter dbcont if you want to continue from here
    end
    ['moving on, it is now: ' datestr(now)]
    pause(3) %Doing some more calculations
end
```

If you want, you can prevent lines being printed to the screen. In this case you need to enter the input at the time the figure window is open (Look in your start bar on windows).

To summarize, the short code that you can put somewhere like a conditional breakpoint would be:

```
if ~isnan(waitinput('',5))
    keyboard; 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After certain version (I don't know which one exactly):

Windows: Ctrl + F5 
Mac: Command + F5 (I guess) 
Unix: I am looking for answer too

After 2016a, there is a button for that on the interface too.