# How to make an interruptible matlab script

Tags: matlab

sometimes I have scripts that run for a long time.
Usually they have some main for-loop and produce data which is collected and returned by the function at the end.

Now if I decide to stop the script after say 1 hour, I loose all the data that has been produced so far.

Is there a good way to create a matlab function that can react to user input while running. I would like to have some kind of stop-button or so...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272541/matlab-stop-and-continue-execution-from-debugger-possible

Comment: Take a look at this conversation http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/6663

Comment: Thanks very much, that's indeed my question, I just didn't find it..

Comment: This is the way I did it (thanks to learnvst for the hint)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272541/matlab-stop-and-continue-execution-from-debugger-possible

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way is to do your long loop in a tight level script, not in a function call.  Then when you interrupt it, you are in the workspace and have all the variables populated as they were when you interrupted, and you can proceed to do what you want with them.

Matlab does not make it easy to interrupt a function and get what you want.  It actually seems pretty insane to me that they don't let you write a forced exit handler.  WTF.

Comment: You can use `onCleanup` to define actions that should be executed on a forced exit.

Comment: @Jonas That is true. However, it does not allow you to "interrupt" the function and see a snapshot of the memory space the function was seeing AND a snapshot of the main memory space you were calling the function from. Ultimately, you could probably simulate these functionalities using save, figuring out how different workspaces are referred to within Matlab, figuring out how to tell yourself where you were when you ran onCleanup and so on. THat requires a lot more learning matlab than the simple suggestion I make, which is why I chose that simple suggestion