# Can you pause MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, debugging, pausing-execution

In MATLAB, I'm running some code which takes a while to run. I'd like to pause the code to check on some variable values. Is there a way I can do this without having to re-run the code from the beginning? I don't want to terminate the program; just pause it.

Comment: You may be interested in reading more about the debugging functions in matlab - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-184

Comment: perhaps this approach might help if you want to interactively pause the code, enter debugging mode, inspect variables, then continue execution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3273167/97160

Answer (score 6):

You can halt execution and give a command prompt in two ways of which I am aware:

- Putting `keyboard` in your code where you want to stop.
- Setting a breakpoint.

You can resume and stop execution with `dbcont` and `dbquit`, respectively.  To step forward, use `dbstep`.  `dbstack` lets you see where you are.  There are many more commands.  The help page for any of these will give you other suggestions.

As Dennis Jaheruddin has pointed out, `dbstop` also has several useful features worth trying.  In particular is the ability to set conditional and global (any line meeting a criterion) breakpoints via the `dbstop if` syntax.  For example, `dbstop if error` will break to a debugging command prompt on any error.  One suggestion he made, which I now do, is to put `dbstop if error` into `startup.m` so that this behavior will be default when you start MATLAB.  You may need to create this file in a `userpath` folder;  `edit(fullfile(regexp(userpath,'^[^;]*','match','once'),'startup.m'))`.

Comment: Note that breakpoints allow you to set conditions (just rightclick on one). This allows you to easily stop every 100th iteration for example, or when a certain condition is met. Also look into `help dbstop`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve what you're looking for would be to use [**code sections**](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html) (also known as code cells), where you divide your code into sections divided by lines with two percent signs (%%).

Then, in the editor, you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to execute the current code section, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+up/down to navigate between sections.

Comment: This is not incorrect. Why the down vote?  Same for my answer for that matter.

Comment: @chappjc: Well, Andreas does have a point that with `pause`, you can't check the workspace variables. For me that alone wouldn't be a reason for a downvote though, and your solution doesn't even have that problem.

Comment: Removed the `pause` suggestion since it didn't fit OP's needs, and expanded on the code sections explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is the pause command, but then you cannot check for the variable contents in the workspace because the program is running.

What you probably want is to set a breakpoint (See the Debug menu / key F12).

At a breakpoint matlab pauses the program and enters debugging mode in which you can see and edit the variables. Once finished, you can resume the program where it was paused.

Comment: You can insert a breakpoint using `keyboard` function without needing to use matlab IDE, which I don't like, btw. Nvm, chappjc already stated it x)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Windows users but if you're running Linux you can start Matlab in a terminal using

```
matlab -nodesktop
```

then once Matlab has started, cd to your project directory and start your Matlab script. Now whenever you want to pause execution you can use `ctrl-Z`. Then to resume type `fg`. I hope this helps.