# How to stop a Matlab script but don’t kill the process?

Tags: matlab

Strg+C stops and kills a Matlab script (at least sometimes). But is there a way to stop a Matlab, take a look at some variables and continue the calculation?

I am not talking about just setting a breakpoint. I want my script, let’s say run for couple hours come back to it hit some buttons that stops the calculations take a look at some variable and then continue the calculation.

I tried to find out if there is some shortcut key for this – I am quite sure there isn’t.

Now I was thinking about including an if-case that looks if a certain button was pressed by the user. If so there would be a useless k=0 line and a breakpoint on it. And if no one is pressing this button the loop would continue. But this is where my limited Matlab knowledge leaves me. I don’t know if there is a way to ask for a user-button press but don’t wait for a button press like in the function `input`. Also I just have a running script, I don’t have any GUI.

Comment: Instead of stopping the process could you save a .mat file at some point and open it in another Matlab instance to look at your variables? I'm just thinking aloud that might be a very bad idea haha.

Comment: not sure how to do that with console script only, but a simple figure with a `pause / resume` button should be rather simple to implement. Additionally, you could use it to display some kind of progress indicator. If your calculations really take hours, the overhead would be unnoticed.

Comment: Sounds like [debugging](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html).

Comment: @horchler, could you explain to me how to set a breakpoint into an already running program?

Comment: for the keypress part check this: http://wiki.stdout.org/matlabcookbook/Collecting%20data/Getting%20time-sensitive%20keyboard%20input/

Comment: Already running? Sounds like you want Matlab to work magic. To do what you ask, you need to do a bit of work *before* you start a program running. This sort of question has been asked before. There is no way to arbitrarily pause a program and look at the memory when it is in some random state. You need to right your code to handle this. Any solution will have some effect on performance (if Matlab was written to allow what you want it would probably be incredibly slow) so watch out for that.

Comment: @horchler, did you even read more than the title? I already explained I am looking for a routine that allows me to stop the loop with a breakpoint at a random time – when I press a button. I just don’t know how to check if a button was pressed but don’t wait for a button press in a script based program. Please compare both your comments to what was already written in the whole question text.

Comment: This is not as simple as you would hope it to be, but fortunately people have thought about it before in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272541/matlab-stop-and-continue-execution-from-debugger-possible Have flagged this one as it appears to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

To drop to the command prompt you need the command `keyboard` and then type `return` when you have finished (you don't need a breakpoint). The tricky bit is how to trigger it. There a few options. The easiest is to open a figure window. The following code halts the process when any key is pressed.

```
keyDownListener=@(src,event) keyboard;
fig = figure;
drawnow
set(fig,'KeyPressFcn',keyDownListener)
for p=1:10000
  %do some thing
end
```

You can modify this to test for a specific key since the keypress is contained within the `event` struct.

To use no figure gui at all its more of a problem. I'm not aware of a non blocking keyboard input method. A mex file the runs kbhit() in C might do it, but kbhit() is not standard C so it would only work on Windows. An easier option maybe to test for the presence of a file.

```
for p=1:100000
if exist(fullfile(pwd,'halt.tmp'),'file')
    keyboard
end
%do something here
end
```

This drops to the debug console when halt.tmp is created in the current directory.

Other potential methods could involve using multiple threads to read 'input' (either the Parallel computer toolbox or undocumented Java code), or using http://psychtoolbox.org/ as mentioned by @bdecaf