# Stopping/pausing execution in Matlab to check the value of the variables while running

Tags: matlab, debugging, variables

I am trying to write a program in Matlab which is quite large and I want to stop or pause the execution to see what my variables values are.

Comment: I solved the issue in a different way and after I finished the project and presented it to professors i completely forgot about it. But it was a very clear and complete answer. Thank you for the explanation. I will probably use it in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to stop or pause the execution to see what my variables are.

One alternative is to use [`keyboard`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html):

> `keyboard` pauses execution of a running program and gives control to
>   the keyboard. Place the `keyboard` function in a program at the location
>   where you want MATLAB® to pause. When the program pauses, the prompt
>   in the Command Window changes to K>>, indicating that MATLAB is in
>   debug mode. You then can view or change the values of variables to see
>   if the new values produce expected results. The keyboard function is
>   useful for debugging your functions.

To continue executing your function, type [`dbcont`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbcont.html), or type [`dbquit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbquit.html) to quit the debug mode.

If you want to view the variables after a given number of iterations you can insert `if ii = stop_point; keyboard;` where `ii` is the iterator of the loop.

---

Another option is:

Use [`dbstop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html). This is shown with an example from the documentation:

> Set a breakpoint to stop when n >= 4, and run the code.

```
dbstop in myprogram at 4 if n>=4
myprogram
```

---

Yet another option is to [manually insert breakpoints in the MATLAB editor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html). Click on the left side of the code to insert breakpoints (indicated by a red dot). Now you can view the variable by hovering the mouse over the variable names in the editor

[image]

Have a look at [this very relevant link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/examine-values.html) to get more information.

---

Note, the following paragraph is a direct copy of [chappjc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2778484/chappjc)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36074605/2338750). Please upvote his/her answer if you like this approach!

With the [release of R2016a](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?refresh=true#bu5rsdy-1), you can just hit the Pause button in the code editor and it will halt right away.

> To pause the execution of a program while it is running, in the Editor
>   tab, click the Pause button. MATLAB pauses execution at the next
>   executable line*. When your code is running, the Start button will
>   turn into a pause:

[image]