# Counting average on huge matrix with conditional

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

The following MATLAB code runs forever on 10^5 square matrix A. However, it runs for a few seconds on 10^3 square matrix. Is there any way to speed it up?

```
function [meanNV]=calcMeanNV_k(A,V,d)
%A: input matrix (n x n)
%V: eigenvectors of k-th largest eigenvalues (n x 1)
%d: degrees of each node (n x 1)
%meanNV: mean of neighbors vectors (n x 1)
m=size(A,2);
meanNV=zeros(113336);
 for i=1:m
     sumNode = 0;
     for j=1:m
        if A(i,j)==1
            sumNode=sumNode+V(j);
        end
     end
    [meanNV(i)]=sumNode/d(i); 
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, for each row in `A`, you are determining the locations that are non-zero and using these indices to sum over the corresponding locations in `V` and dividing by the corresponding entry in `d`.

First use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to determine the non-zero row and column locations, then group all of the column locations by their common rows using [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and the function to apply on `accumarray` would simply sum over all indices once you index into `V`.

Something like this could work:

```
function [meanNV]=calcMeanNV_k1(A,V,d)
%A: input matrix (n x n)
%V: eigenvectors of k-th largest eigenvalues (n x 1)
%d: degrees of each node (n x 1)
%meanNV: mean of neighbors vectors (n x 1)

m=size(A,2);
[row,col] = find(A); % Find non-zero entries in A
meanNV = accumarray(row, col, [m 1], @(x) sum(V(x))) ./ d; % Compute desired result

end
```

Comment: Hi @rayryeng, thanks for your help. I made a mistake in the previous code. The initialization of sumNode=0; should be outside of the inner for loop. A represents links between nodes. If node i and j are connected, then A(i,j) = 1. Otherwise, A(i,j) = 0.

I want to get the average of all the eigen vectors of neighbor nodes of i. Neighbor nodes are all nodes that have connection with node i, where A(i,j) = 1. It should accumulate all V(j) that has 1 in the corresponding location in A. Then divide the sum with d(i). d(i) represents the degree/total number of connections from node i. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This what works:

```
function [meanNV]=calcMeanNV_k1(A,V,d)
%A: input matrix (n x n)
%V: eigenvectors of k-th largest eigenvalues (n x 1)
%d: degrees of each node (n x 1)
%meanNV: mean of neighbors vectors (n x 1)
tic
m=size(A,2);
meanNV=zeros(m,1);
idx = A == 1;
for k = 1:m
   meanNV = sum(V(idx(k,:)));
end
meanNV = meanNV./d;
toc
```

Comment: I'd like to write an answer that doesn't use loops.... which I can guarantee is faster. Would you like to see?

Comment: Sure. This takes 10 minutes to run.

Comment: Thanks for the accept! How much faster is the code I wrote?

Comment: It only took 2 seconds to run. Thanks.

Comment: That's crazy.  That must mean your matrix must have been very sparse to be reduced from 10 minutes to 2 seconds.  Good to hear!